# Use ajax with FOSJsRoutingBundle

Tags: ajax, symfony

I have an action to set a Travel enabled , it works good but now I'd like to make it with ajax so I have installed **FOSJsRoutingBundle** but the problem is that I don't know how to write the ajax code.

**Route**

```
travel_enable:
path:     /travel/enable/{id}
defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Travel:enable" }
options:
    expose: true
```

Action

```
    public function enableAction(Travel $travel)
    {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $travel->setEnabled(true);

    $em->flush();

    $referer = $this->getRequest()->headers->get('referer');
    return $this->redirect($referer);
}
```

twig

```
<a href="{{ path('travel_enable', {'id': entity.id} ) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" title="Enable"> Enable </a>
```

javascript

```
<script type="javascript">
    // what to put here else

    Routing.generate('travel_enable', { id: '...' });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a any other reason behind using `FOSJsRoutingBundle` than because of ajax capability?

If no, you could remove it and pre-generate all URLs needed. Something like this

**Twig:**

```
<a href="{{ path('travel_enable', {'id': entity.id} ) }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-success dyn-link" title="Enable"> Enable </a>
```

**JS:**

```
$('a.dyn-link').on('click', function(){
    var URL = $(this).attr('href');

    $.post(URL, {
        // Your post data here, if any
    }).done(function(response){
        alert("Suceess!");
    }).error(function(){
        alert("Error!");
    });
});
```

Now, **the diffrent approach** is needed when you dynamically generate your `<a>` tags, in which case **you will need** `FOSJsRoutingBundle`:

**Twig:**

```
<a data-entity-id="YOUR-ENTITY-ID-GOES-HERE" class="btn btn-xs btn-success dyn-link" title="Enable"> Enable </a>
```

**JS:**

```
// You have to use event delegate
$(body).on('click', 'a.dyn-link', function(){
    var entityId = $(this).attr('data-entity-id');

    var URL = Routing.generate('travel_enable', { id: entityId });

    $.post(URL, {
        // Your post data here, if any
    }).done(function(response){
        alert("Suceess!");
    }).error(function(){
        alert("Error!");
    });
});
```

Hope this helps...